# How is the spacing between buttons on Bootstrap docs achieved?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I can't figure out how the buttons are horizontally separated so neatly [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/buttons/#outline-buttons) without the aid of left and right margins.

Does anyone know how this is done?

[image]

Comment: the duplicate explain how to remove that space but also explain why there is a space too (you don't need the remove part)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The display method used for all of Bootstrap's `.btn` components is `inline-block` which makes them privy to the feature or bug (depending on your perspective) of honoring the white space created by carriage returns or spaces between each `inline-block` item.

Comment: That explains it. But it didn't make a difference when I changed `display` to `inline`.